# Process a sass file in webpack multiple times (multiple configurations)

Tags: javascript, webpack

I use SASS files with variables that change value depending on the target website.

In order to handle that, I thought that I could ask webpack to generate two external CSS files, one per target website.

I have tried the following configuration:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var extract1 = new ExtractTextPlugin('assets/styles.1.css'));
var extract2 = new ExtractTextPlugin('assets/styles.2.css'));

module.exports = {
    /* snip - pretty standard configuration with single entry point */
    module: {
        loaders: [
            /* ... snip ... */
            /* Support for SASS. */
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: [extract1.extract(['css-loader','sass-loader?config=sassLoaderConfig1'])]
            },             
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: [extract2.extract(['css-loader','sass-loader?config=sassLoaderConfig2'])]
            },             
        ]
    },

    sassLoaderConfig1: {
        data: "@import 'variables1.scss';\n"
    },
    sassLoaderConfig2: {
        data: "@import 'variables2.scss';\n"
    },

    plugins: [extract1,extract2],

    /* snip */
}
```

However, only `styles.1.css` is generated - I guess that a single file can only be taken by a single loader.
How can I get webpack to output both files, with different variables?

I am currently using Webpack 1.

Comment: Hi Jean ;)

The problem here is that webpack will match the first rule's regex and miss the second one.

Usually, you'll have 3 files `webpack.common.conf.js`, `webpack.target1.conf.js`, `webpack.target2.conf.js` where the last two configs override the first one then you just run different builds for your different targets during deployment.

I'll let you posted if I find any other way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example on a github repo: https://github.com/wishtack/wt-webpack-a-b-testing-example

There are two branches `parallel-webpack` and `hack-sass-a-b-testing`.

IMHO, the first one is the cleanest as it will build two apps with different `common.scss` files.

The second one will run one build and output two style files. It's more optimized as you can share webpack chunks between both outputs.
The problem is that it will load all your SASS files with a wildcard and put them in a CSS file.
There are two problems with this approach:
- You'll load all the SASS files even useless ones.
- It won't work with Angular 2+ as the framework will override each component's CSS or use shadow DOM. With this approach, the CSS is global and that's dirty.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your samples! I will admit that I was missing a fundamental part (how to specify multiple configurations, with different entry points / configurations) of webpack. I will look into it when I am back at work. ;)

Comment: By which I mean, I have already looked at your samples, and I see how I could modify the project to use multiple configurations and `parallel-webpack`.

Comment: In the end, I was able to set multiple project configurations with webpack 1. However, there are currently two issues: first, because of our (somewhat byzantine) build system, I was not able to set the build to use `parallel-webpack` - so I am launching the build of the two variants in a single node process; second, for some reason, trying to use webpack watch (with our build system) on a list of configurations fails. We probably want to upgrade to webpack 2 eventually, so that should be fine in the meantime. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try using include.

```
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: "assets/styles.1.css"
        loaders: [extract1.extract(['css-loader','sass-loader?config=sassLoaderConfig1'])]
    },             
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: "assets/styles.2.css"
        loaders: [extract2.extract(['css-loader','sass-loader?config=sassLoaderConfig2'])]
    },
```